# Plot 3D positions of nonzero elements in 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `M` of size `981 x 567 x 1154`.

`M` is a matrix of zeros, with `122` 1's in specific X,Y,Z locations.

How can I plot this in 3D to see the distribution of these 1's in matlab?

**Note**: If I use `scatter3()` or `plot3()` functions, I must provide `3` arguments - the X, Y, and Z vectors. I am essentially interested in how to transform the `M` matrix into these 3 inputs so I can pass them onto the functions.

Comment: What is the meaning of your data? You can use [`scatter3`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) to visualise data points in 3D.

Comment: `Z` is a matrix of zeros, with `122` 1's in specific X,Y,Z locations.

Comment: If I use `scatter3()` or `plot3()` functions, I must provide `3` arguments - the X, Y, and Z vectors. I am essentially interested in how to transform the `M` matrix into these 3 inputs so I can pass them onto such functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to obtain the linear indices of the non-zero elements and convert them to 3D indices with [`ind2sub`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) as follows:

```
[I] = find(M);
[X, Y, Z] = ind2sub(size(M),I);
```

Now you can use [`scatter3`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) to plot your 3D points as follows:

```
scatter3(X, Y, Z)
```

This will give you the following result for a small example matrix `M` defined as:

```
M = zeros(5,5,5);
M(2,1,1) = 1;
M(1,4,5) = 1;
M(2,2,2) = 1;
M(3,2,2) = 1;
```

[image]